# Get a reference to a Vue child element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js component where the template looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="map" />
    <div class="something-else" />
  </div>
</template>
```

In the `<script>` portion I'd like to get a reference to the element with class `map`. I know you can use `this.$el` to reference the outermost element, but how would I select one of its children? I'd prefer not use the CSS class as a selector, since there could be many instances of this component that all have the same class.

My use case is I need to pass in a DOM element to the [constructor](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-constructor) for Leaflet, a mapping library.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about Leaflet, but you would probably use a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="map" ref="map" />
    <div class="something-else" />
  </div>
</template>
```

In your component

```
mounted(){
    new Leaflet(this.$refs.map)
}
```